# How to create a new share link for Dropbox folder in Orangedox

Tags: dropbox, orangedox

Is it possible to create a new share link for a Dropbox folder with Orangedox?

Answer (score 2):

Not as of yet is isn't, you can only track files .. but it is something we will be adding to the next version of Orangedox in the coming couple of months.

EDIT (Jan 8th 2015):

Our latest version of PRO now lets you track folders, see when someone downloaded or previewed your files in shared folders